# Page flashes the Splash page with condition of user logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js

I have set up a user authentication where if user logged in, show a specific page, but if not, show the splash screen.

So like for `localhost:3000/` (the home page, should show splash screen or the dashboard of the logged in user)

How can I ensure that it should only show the correct page without flashing the splash screen?

Home component (or the dashboard)

```
const Home = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();

  const MainComponent = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <SidebarNav />
        <main className="flex-1 bg-gray-100">
          code goes here
        </main>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      {user ? (
        <div>{MainComponent()}</div>
      ) : (
        <SplashPage />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

My user auth:

```
const UserContext = createContext({});

export default function AuthContext({ children }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    checkUser();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    Hub.listen("auth", () => {
      // perform some action to update state whenever an auth event is detected
      checkUser();
    });
  }, []);

  const checkUser = async () => {
    try {
      // code to get user
    } catch (err) {
      // no current signed in user
      console.log("error with AuthContext", err);
      setUser(null);
    }
  };
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useUser = () => useContext(UserContext);
```

and my _app.js

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page);
  return <AuthContext>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</AuthContext>;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Because you're executing the user check on the client-side you'll always have the content that was pre-rendered on the server (unauthenticated) display first, hence the splash page flashing. Have you considered moving the check to the server instead (if at all possible)?

Comment: @juliomalves So like, do `ServerSideProps` with checking user? Am I able to write this within AuthContext still? Or this doesn't work with context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to put 3 status on your auth process. **loading**, **authenticated** & **unauthenticated**. so the missing part is the loading.

All you need to do now is to change **setUser(null) in checkUser to **{}** or **false****. which make you to know what authentication status you are in

```
  const checkUser = async () => {
    try {
      // code to get user
    } catch (err) {
      // no current signed in user
      console.log("error with AuthContext", err);
      setUser(false);
    }
  };
```

In dashboard component:

```
const Home = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();

  //loading state, show nothing
  if(user===null) return null
  if(user===false) return <SplashPage />
  
  return <>
        <SidebarNav />
        <main className="flex-1 bg-gray-100">
          code goes here
        </main>
      </>

export default Home;
```

Comment: How would you go about using server side authentication? instead of using your current solution? Or what about doing something in my context page?

Comment: @hellomello SSR is mostly for SEO, and when you activate you disable Static generation. authenticated needs client user that has cookies/token anyway. 

So I recommend to process Auth checking on client instead.