# Next JS and Firebase authentication protected routes

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I am using Firebase and Next JS for a webapp where you have to login to be able to access any other page (all routes are protected). What I first did was set up a provider in _app.js so that I can access the status of the user (logged in or not). Then, when a protected page is requested, I check the user status and redirect to the login page when needed like this:

```
import Users from "../components/users/Users";
import Layout from "../components/general/Layout";

import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../components/authentication/auth";

import router from "next/router";

function users() {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      console.log("signed in!");
    } else if (currentUser == null) {
      router.push("/login");
    }
  }, [currentUser]);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Users />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default users;
```

Now, this works in principle, but the redirect takes some time and first shows the "users" page before it redirects. I know there is this option:
https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth

However, I don't like being dependent on this, and was wondering if there is a better, straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: Check my answer and comments here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69092396/page-flashes-the-splash-page-with-condition-of-user-logged-in/69092675

Comment: Can you include your `AuthContext` source in your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, regardless of the value of `currentUser`, you are rendering your `Users` component tree. To prevent this, you need to return `null` from your component (to hide it) while it is still loading. Because you also don't want to render anything when a user is signed out, you should return `null` for that too.

```
function users() { // <- rename this to something else, like `UsersPage`
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      console.log("signed in!");
    } else if (currentUser == null) {
      router.push("/login");
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  if (!currentUser) {
    // user is signed out or still being checked.
    // don't render anything
    return null;
  }

  // if here, user is signed in, show the component
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Users />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Could you elaborate on your suggestion to rename? It seems natural to have a url like: website.com/users instead of UsersPage. Do you think it will cause problems somewhere?

Comment: @round_circle By convention, components (which this function is) are named in TitleCase. You could use `Users` on its own, but that conflicts with the child component. The name of a component has nothing to do with what URL it is served over.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot, the name of the folder is the url! Thanks again.

Comment: In the next JS docs they have primarily elaborated on two patterns. You will be better suited for server side rendering if you want to prevent flash of unauthenticated content. I believe the above solution works but is a bit 'hacky'. Find more information here: [auth patterns](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication)